# Hive: How to select the middle element order by some column

Tags: sql, hive, emr

What is the hive query to select the middle element ordered by some column.

Example:

```
Name      age
A          10
B          20
C          30
```

Output: `B   20`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the middle row using analytic functions row_number() and count() like so:

```
select name, age
from (
select
    name,
    age,
    row_number() over (order by your_order_by_list) r,
    count(*) over () c
from
    your_table) t
where r = cast((c + 1) / 2 as int);
```

Answer (score 1):

The middle element is the median of the column.  There are several ways to do this.  A reliable way is:

```
select avg(age)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by age) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum * 2 in (cnt, cnt + 1, cnt + 2);
```

This works for both even and odd numbers of rows.  It does assume that "age" is numeric (so `avg()` will work).

Comment: How will it give correct output in case of odd number of elements? It will take average of two values and return a value which is not even part of the actual data.

To calculate median a reliable way is also by using percentile(0.5) function.

Comment: @Adi . . . Off by 1.  See the revision.  It calculates the median correctly, and you don't have to remember whether you want `percentile_disc()` or `percentile_cont()` and how they handle equal values.